Can i connect the display of a Aures Sango to a new Client
I would like to know whether there is a way to connect the display of an Aures Sango i5 Edition to a client that is able to run Windows 11. The display cable has a 50 pin connection to the mainboard. I cannot find the name of this connection on the Internet or if there is an adapter for it. Using Linux is not possible since our POS is programmed for Windows only. Any Ideas are welcome. If any Information are missing that would help to solve this, please let me know. Thanks in advance.
